# Validate not nil/blank element in array / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, validation

```
a = ["1", "2", " ", nil]
```

-- Validate: Are filled all elements? (not nil, not blank)

How to?

Answer (score 8):

That's simple:

```
a = ["1", "2", " ", nil]

a.any?(&:blank?)   #=> true

a.all?(&:present?) #=> false
```

Comment: `all?` will stop after finding `false`, so no difference in speed.

Comment: @VictorMoroz: Yes, you are right. I was thinking about a different scenario.